# extract the values of the base and quote currency from forex pairs in pine script

Tags: pine-script, forex

In Pine script, is there a way of extracting the values of the  base and quote currency from forex pairs pls?

what i mean is, using AUDCAD as an example, is there a way of finding the value of AUD and that of CAD pls?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will find these in the reference document.
`syminfo.basecurrency` for example

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_syminfo{dot}basecurrency](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dbasecurrency)

Comment: Thanks but I am not interested in obtaining the base currency symbol, but am interesetd in the numerical values of the base and quote currency, anyone ? thanks

Comment: u need to use request.security to get the base currency quote, u can create the ticker and then use request.security to fetch the quote